# What determines the spot of a field goal kick in the NFL?

Tags: rules, american-football, nfl, field-goal

Is there a limit to how close the ball gets spotted behind the line of scrimmage during a field goal attempt?

I regularly watch the NFL and on the field goals the holder awaits for the ball about 8 yards behind the line of scrimmage. It seems like the ball is always kicked from 8 yards behind the scrimmage no matter the yardage of the kick; ie. if it's a 20 yard attempt or a 60 yarder. Although at times this distance looks to be much closer to 7 yards than 8. Is there a rule that dictates this distance has to be respected or all teams have converged to kick about 8 yard behind the scrimmage over time?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no rule about the required *exact* distance from the line of scrimmage. It can be taken from the line itself or behind. They kick from 7 yards behind the line primarily because they're used to it.

The only rule covering this is **Rule 11.4.1 Successful Field Goal** ([link](https://operations.nfl.com/media/2725/2017-playing-rules.pdf)):

> a) The kick must be a placekick or dropkick made by the offense from on
>   or behind the line of scrimmage or from the spot of a fair catch (fair
>   catch kick). If a fair catch is made or awarded outside the inbound
>   line, the spot of the kick is the nearest inbound line.
>   (...)

However, because Field Goal trys have little to no margin for errors the players will do anything they can to succeed. This includes a fair distance from the LoS and always the same distance whenever possible...

- A shorter distance may get the ball blocked while a longer distance is harder to snap and an unnecessary extra distance for the kick.
- The snap needs to be very precise in order to give the holder the chance to place the ball correctly before the kicker arrives. That would be a difficult task if the distance is varying.

**TL;DR:**

It's allowed to use other distances, but it would be an unnecessary risk (and a lot of extra training work). That's why they don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

There actually is a rule that applies here, and it pertains to legal formations. Field goals are kicked from a scrimmage kick formation, and in order to be a legal scrimmage kick formation, the holder must be a minimum of 7 yards behind the line of scrimmage.

While it's legal to kick a field goal from a formation that's not a scrimmage kick formation (i.e. it would still count),doing so voids all protections due the kicker, holder, and snapper. It also negates the numbering exception (NCAA: 5 linemen numbered 50-79; NFL: ends must be eligible). So even though there's no reason a kicker can't set up more than 7 yards back (a slight but low possibility for a long, low trajectory kick), you'll never see the kicker be closer than that, because of the formation rules.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).